# USB-C AlternateMode not working even after upgrading kernel to 4.19

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, display, displayport

I have been trying to use an external display with my hp-envy-13 running ubuntu 18.04 for a while now. I was expecting that kernel 4.19 would have the support but it still does not seem to work. The adapter (usb-c to VGA) works smoothly with my Macbook, ruling out any cable/adapter issues, but is not recognised on ubuntu.

Am I missing something here?

```
    $ uname -a
    Linux HP-ENVY-Laptop-13-ad1xx 4.19.0-041900-generic #201810221809 SMP Mon Oct 22 22:11:45 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


    $ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
    Release:    18.04
    Codename:   bionic


    $ lspci -d ::0c03 -k
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd


    $ lspci -vt
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
       +-02.0  Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620
       +-04.0  Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
       +-08.0  Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
       +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
       +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
       +-15.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
       +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
       +-17.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
       +-1c.0-[01]----00.0  Alcor Micro Device 6625
       +-1c.5-[02]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 7265
       +-1d.0-[03]----00.0  Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116
       +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Device 9d4e
       +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
```

Comment: Comparing hw support in mac to Linux seems a bit far fetched

Comment: First step would be to look in `dmesg` when you plug in the adapter to see if there's any reaction. Getting Mac hardware to work under Linux won't be easy in general, because there's little documentation for the hardware. So even if alternate mode works, the Mac hardware may require additional stuff Linux doesn't know about.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the suggestion. `dmesg` does not register any response when plugging in the adapter, it does register a response when plugging any other device in the same port so I am guessing the issue is with alternate mode support in my system. I mentioned about cable working with MAC just to rule out faulty cable issues. My understanding was that Kernel 4.19 would support alternate mode on USB-C ports, same is mentioned in the release notes. So if its not working for me, I am assuming that I am missing something.

Comment: Guess: The alternate mode support so far only works for host controllers adhering to some kind of standard, not for whatever Apple does (after all, they'll also support Thunderbolt in a similar way).

Comment: How old is "The adapter (usb-c to VGA)"? Is it from Apple?

Comment: Adapter was fairly new at that time, It's not from apple.